# Location determination in electromagnetic digital pen

Tags: coil, induction

I was reading an [article](https://www.androidauthority.com/break-it-down-how-does-the-s-pen-work-154435/#:%7E:text=The%20answer%3A%20the%20S%20Pen,emanates%20outward%20from%20the%20screen.) that explains how SPen from Samsung works. There is one coil in pen. I think there should be one or multiple coils on the sides of the tablet. I guess other graphic tablets may also use the [same mechanism](https://www.businesstoday.in/magazine/know-tech/graphics-tablet/story/20837.html#:%7E:text=A%20graphics%20tablet%20is%20a,as%20a%20file%20or%20document.).

> My question is, how can S pen find the location? Are there multiple coils in the tablet, or is there just one? As in these cases the tablet can detect the pen from about 10mm distance, the capacitive or resistive touch is not responsible for this and there might be another mechanism.

I've also read [this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6138896.) that shows that it is possible to measure the distance with the aid of two coils. Does this pen use the same mechanism?

Comment: I feel the coil is only for power transfer. Location is still found by capacitive panel of touch screen. Pressure is sensed using the pen circuit and that data is transferred wirelessly. Phone will then use the location (position) and pressure data to give you the desired experience.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack According to the link, the pen also works from a distance where the pen does not touch the panel.

Comment: Wacom is a company that makes tablets with and without displays which can be "drawn on" using a pressure sensitive stylus that has no battery. Wacom holds many patents on this technology. It is possible that Samsung licensed some if this technology. You might find more information on how the technology works by reading this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wacom  or searching on Google Patents: https://www.google.com/?tbm=pts Also watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ix0mN8agzo

Comment: @sma - even Capacitive can work at a certain distance (2-3 mm) if sensitivity is increased. Some android phones used to come with glove mode. When turned on, you can use it while wearing gloves. I'm guessing it's the same thing.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack, If you watch this: https://youtu.be/7Ix0mN8agzo?t=169  you can see that the location of the pen is already found at a much larger distance. The phone has to be using some of the same technology that is used in Wacom's tablets where the location is found even if the pen is around 10 mm above the tablet's surface.

Comment: Send me a working phone + pen and I'll tear it down for you and tell you how it (probably) works. You could also ask Samsung but they will probably not tell you. Go read this Patent: https://patents.google.com/patent/US5635684A/en  I'm not saying that that what is used but the technology will probably be quite similar. Can you understand how it works from the patent? If no then study to become electrical engineer in order to understand it.

Comment: @bimpel - thanks for the link. sma - I might be horribly wrong. Excuse me.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack Your idea could have worked also and would probably be cheaper as well but maybe less accurate.